# Get the size of a file, with uploading and POST request

Tags: node.js, post, file-upload

**Please note:** I want to do this with vanilla Node.

I want to upload a file with the `input type="file"` HTML tag, and in the same form element hit a submit button `input type="submit"` and get the size of the file in bytes when I submit a POST request.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?!!!

Comment: I have no idea how to do this in pure Node.js, that's why I asked the question to professionals like yourself.

Comment: Does anyone know ?!

Comment: @dNitro you don't know how to write it either huh ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  switch (req.url) {
    case '/':
      display_form(req, res);
      break;
    case '/upload':
      show_bytes(req, res);
      break;
    default:
      res.writeHead(404, {'content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('not found');
      res.end();
      break;
  }
});
server.listen(3000);

function display_form(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(
    '<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload">'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Submit">'+
    '</form>'
  );
  res.end();
}

function show_bytes(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write(req.headers['content-length'] +  ' bytes');
  res.end();
}
```

Comment: This does work, but the Byte size is slightly off. Very slightly larger than the actual size. Why is that?

Comment: Any ideas on this @dNitro

Comment: @JohnNoob, I didn't notice that, but really seems every time it adds an overhead about ~230 bytes to actual size. Normally **content-length** header should be the same size of incoming body. Maybe its because of *chunked* encoding?! I really got no idea. You may consider it as a new question, maybe someone out there could help us.

Comment: The reason it's off is because the `content-length` is the size of the entire request (headers, other form fields, etc). I'm not sure there is a way to get the size of an uploaded file until the file data has been streamed to the server - you count the bytes of individual files as they come in. A tool like [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) can help you do this.